# Magento 2 Admin Portal ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I made a copy of a working magento installation in docker image and put it into another vm with orther ip adress (staging env) and same docker image. I want to create a staging environment where I can test deploying security patches and perform other updates before I deploy it to live

what I did:

I clone database with sql dump from test to staging

then i runed this cmds:

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://my_staging_env_ip"
rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache/* generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR -f
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
```

the main website work fine but the admin portal enters in loop redirection with a 302 status and give me a wired url like this

```
http://{ip-staging}/admin/http:/admin/admin/index/index/key/f3327bb999d2fa7577a5e2817a09628fe74cxdsca46e06c82cf690f221004d7d/
```

To solve this problem i have to open admin portal with web browser and get in loop redirection then write one of this commandes

```
bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1
```

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

```
bin/magento config:set web/cookie/cookie_httponly 0
```

my problem that I want to automate this process without opening admin portal with my web browser then type cache flush

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably caused by the admin portal attempting to load the javascript and CSS files via normal HTTP instead of HTTPS.

To correct this, please try to set Use Secure URLs in Admin to true, in System -> Config -> General -> Web.

Comment: my secure url is set same as unsecure

Comment: I think that I solved my problem the solution is under test I found that I'm using a custom base url  **base-url** instance of **base_url**